# How to obtain the list of all environment variables in Vim?

Tags: vim, environment-variables

When Vim is started, it grabs many of the environment variables from the operating system (like `PATH`) and it also sets it own environment variables (like `MYVIMRC`).

How do I *list* or view all the environment variables that Vim understands, together with their respective values from inside Vim?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_the_current_Vim_environment could be of help

Comment: So you're looking for a complete list of env vars vim inherits, or are you looking for all env vars Vim creates on its own (by itself)?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to do that by Vim-only means.  However, in Unix-like systems one can just use `:!env`.

Comment: Tarek Fadel: As indicated in my question, I am interested in both. Vim too, refers to both, as environment variables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Vimscript, there is not a direct way of getting the list of
currently defined environment variables. However, it is possible
to exploit Vim command-line completion feature to make one.

Consider possible completions for the following unfinished command:

```
:echo $
```

It is not difficult to see that, according to Vimscript syntax,
the completions must be the names of the environment variables.
Pressing the `wildchar` key (<kbd>Tab</kbd>, by default) or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will display all of them.

In order to get this list of completions from within a script, we need
to overcome its interactive nature. A possible trick that I propose
herein relies on a combination of features. The first of them is the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> command. In Command-line mode, this
shortcut triggers insertion of every available completion in front of
the cursor. The inserted completions are listed in alphabetical order
and separated with spaces.

If we could make Vim print those completions out right into the
command line, we would easily capture them by redirecting command
output with the `:redir` command. But all we need to achieve that
side effect is to quote the text inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:
Quoting makes the rest of our `:echo` command a string literal that
can be just printed out!

```
:echo 'NAME1 NAME2 NAME3'
NAME1 NAME2 NAME3
```

To edit the command line in this way, the user can type `:ec` (an
alias for `:echo`) followed by `$`, press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `'`, jump to the beginning of the
line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, move the cursor over
the dollar sign by pressing <kbd>⇾</kbd> (the right arrow key) twice,
delete that `$`, and, finally, insert `'` instead. The same sequence
of key presses can easily be reproduced non-interactively using the
`:normal` command.

Putting all these pieces together, we obtain the following function:

```
function! Env()
    redir => s
    sil! exe "norm!:ec$\<c-a>'\<c-b>\<right>\<right>\<del>'\<cr>"
    redir END
    return split(s)
endfunction
```

For this approach to work, Vim must be compiled with the
`+cmdline_compl` feature.

Comment: It is better to change `echo` to `return`: that works for me: `execute "fu! Test()\nexe'silent normal!:return $\<C-a>'')\<C-b>\<C-right>\<Right>\<Del>split('''.\"\\n\"\nendfu"`.

Answer (score 23):

To list all environment variables, use

```
:echo $<C-D>
```

Then, you can start typing the name of the variable of interest, auto-complete with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show its value.

You didn't tell whether you need this interactively or in a script. For the latter, it's unfortunately not possible to capture the output via `:redir`.

Comment: Ingo Karkat: Thanks. Interactive is fine with me.

Comment: It is possible to capture command-line completion using `:redir`.  It requires a non-trivial trick, though.  If interested, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11192777/254635).

Answer (score 8):

The previous answers have been made obsolescent by the vimscript **environ()** function.

For example, to list them all in order:

```
:let evars = environ()
:for var in evars->keys()->sort()
:    echo var . '=' . evars[var]
:endfor
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the other anwers, you can do it without a script.

Enter insert mode, and then press

```
<C-R>=
```

Where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> allows you to insert any of the registers available (see :help i_Ctrl-R).  But particularly you'll use the expression register <kbd>=</kbd> here to evaluate a string (see :help @=).

So, now you can insert the expression introduced by ib.'s answer.  Enter this:

```
$<C-A>"<HOME>"<CR><ESC>
```

Now, you should be back to normal mode and the expression should have evaluated to a string and been placed in the buffer.  You can further clean it up with a substitute command:

```
:s/\s/\r$/g
```

That should place every environment variable on a different line.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea by ib and the comments from ZyX, here's the function that I ended up using:

```
function! GetEnvVars()
    silent execute "normal! :return $\<C-a>')\<C-b>\<C-right>\<Right>\<Del>split('\<CR>"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:let
```

displays all (inc current buffer/windows) variables. Or, if you need to list e.g. all window scope variable, use this isntead:

```
:let w:
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```vimscript
:put =reduce(items(environ()), {a,e->a..e[0]..'='..e[1]..nr2char(10)}, '')
```

Explanation

| syntax | description |
| --- | --- |
| `:put` | [inserts the contents of a register to the edit buffer](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput) |
| `=` | [virtual register that evaluates an expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput:%7E:text=The%20register,command.) |
| `reduce(` | typical [reduce function](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#reduce%28%29), requires vim >= 8.2.0878 (2021) |
| `items(` | [get a list of the (key, value) pairs of a dictionary](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#items%28%29) |
| `environ()` | [a dictionary containing environment variables](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#environ%28%29) vim >= 8.1.1305 (2019) |
| `,` | `reduce()`'s second argument - the reducer function |
| `{a,e->` | start a two argument [lambda function](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-lambda). `a` is the accumulator, `e` is a length 2 array (key, value) pair. |
| `a..` | [string append](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-..) to the accumulator variable `a` |
| `e[0]` | the environment variable name |
| `..'='` | string append a literal equals sign |
| `..e[1]` | string append the environment variable value |
| `..nr2char(10)` | string append a newline character; why not `"\n"`? [because :put= doesn't play nicely with double quotes.](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20escape,command.). You could use `\"\n\"`, though. |
| `}` | end lambda |
| `, ''` | third argument to reduce: the inital accumulator value (empty string) |
| `)` | close reduce call and *fin*. |

in vim9script:

```vim9script
command! PutEnv {
    put =reduce(items(environ()),  (a, e) => a .. e[0] .. '=' .. e[1] .. '\n')
}
```