# In vim, how do I redirect the output of a vimscript function?

Tags: redirect, echo, vim

I have this vimscript function

```
 function! Env()
     redir => s
     sil! exe "norm!:ec$\<c-a>'\<c-b>\<right>\<right>\<del>'\<cr>"
     redir END
     return split(s)
 endfunction
```

This function was obtained from this question:
[How to list all the environment variables in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175842/how-to-list-all-the-environment-variables-in-vim)

When I do `:call Env()` I don't see any output, but `:echo Env()` displays as output the names of all environment variables.

I'd rather copy and paste this output somehow.  I know about `:redir`.  However this doesn't work:

```
:redir @A
:echo Env()
:redir END
"ap
```

Instead, a blank line is pasted.

I have tried many combinations of the `:redir` command (to registers and/or files) and variations on `call Env()` without success.  Is this because the output generated is from calling a function?  I thought it might be because the function returns a list, but `:echo string(Env())` isn't captured by `:redir` either.

Edit: 
This is the modified solution I used from the answer below.

```
function! Env()
    redir => s
    sil! exe "norm!:ec$\<c-a>'\<c-b>\<right>\<right>\<del>'\<cr>"
    redir END
    let @s = string(split(s))
endfunction
```

One can then execute `:call Env()` and then `"sp` to paste.

related question:
[How to redirect ex command output into current buffer or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/vim-how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file?lq=1)

Comment: This is a problem with `:redir` that's being discussed [on the vim_dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/H3Z3ChSUh_4/beZs6KzYdBsJ). In short, nested `:redir` isn't possible.

Comment: I edited my question --- is there a way to modify `Env()` to output, say, to a register or global variable that I can access after a `call Env()` command?

Comment: Note that `:redir @A` *appends* to register "a.  If you want to overwrite it, use lowercase: `:redir @a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, this is a problem with `:redir` that's being discussed [on vim_dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/H3Z3ChSUh_4/beZs6KzYdBsJ). In short, nested redirection with `:redir` isn't possible.

But of course you can simply modify your `Env()` function to redirect output to a register or global variable.

Just change `redir => s` to either `redir => g:s` (global variable `g:s`) or `redir @s` (register `s`), and remove the return statement. Let's use the register:

```
function! Env()
    redir @s
    sil! exe "norm!:ec$\<c-a>'\<c-b>\<right>\<right>\<del>'\<cr>"
    redir END
endfunction
```

After calling the function, the output is stored in register `s` and you can put it with `"sp`, of course.

Comment: Thank you.  I modified this solution slightly to format the output before storing it in `@s` (as shown in the edit to my question).

Answer (score 0):

```
:let @a+=Env()
```

instead of

> ```
> :redir @A
> :echo Env()
> :redir END
> ```

is much more concise, but doesn't print `Env()`'s output to the screen.

(The asker @Ein's modified solution does neither.)

Comment: (Or `:let @A=` equivalently to `:let @a+=`.)